# Getting a Recursive Query to work in Access 2013

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, recursion, vba

After a day's worth of research, I thought I was just at the finish line with my problem.  I got myself all schooled up on recursive queries and managed to get it to execute beautifully in SQL Server Management Studio 2014.  However, I was immediately shot down when translating the query I wrote in SQL Server 2014 into my Access 2013 application.  Reading other articles, I now understand that Access does not support recursive queries.  With that, I need help finding a resource-efficient way to pull these records and put them into an array variable.  My past efforts in emulating this in VBA were horrific; resulting in 30-60 seconds to process.  Any advise on how to lean this process out would be greatly appreciated.

The recursive query I would like to emulate is:

```
WITH MyCTE(BusinessUnitID, Active)
AS(

SELECT a.BusinessUnitID, a.Active
FROM t_EMS_BM_BusinessUnits AS a
WHERE BusinessUnitID = 7

UNION ALL

SELECT d.BusinessUnitID, d.Active
FROM MyCTE AS c
INNER JOIN t_EMS_BM_BusinessUnits AS d
ON c.BusinessUnitID = d.ParentUnit)

SELECT *
FROM MyCTE
WHERE Active = 1
```

My atrocious VBA script is:

```vb
Private Sub LoadArray(intBU As Integer)
    'set rollup data for business unit by adding all child units to intBUs array
    Dim sql As String
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim intCount As Integer

    sql = "SELECT BusinessUnitID, ParentUnit FROM t_EMS_BM_BusinessUnits WHERE Active = true ORDER BY BusinessUnitID"
    Set rs = currentdb.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

    'look for child units
    With rs

        intCount = 0
        ReDim intBUs(1 To 1) As Integer

        If Not .EOF And Not .BOF Then
            .MoveLast
            .MoveFirst

            Do While Not .EOF

                If IsChild(intBU, !BusinessUnitID) = True Then
                    'add to array
                    intCount = intCount + 1

                    If intCount > 1 Then
                        ReDim Preserve intBUs(1 To UBound(intBUs) + 1) As Integer
                        intBUs(UBound(intBUs)) = !BusinessUnitID
                    ElseIf intCount = 1 Then
                        intBUs(UBound(intBUs)) = !BusinessUnitID
                    End If

                End If

                .MoveNext
            Loop
        End If
        .Close
    End With

    Set rs = Nothing

Private Function IsChild(TargetBU, CurrentBU As Integer) As Boolean
    'check if unit is lowest level child
    'is TargetBU a child of CurrentBU?

    Dim intX As Integer
    Dim intCount As Integer

    intX = 0

    If TargetBU = CurrentBU Then
        'return a value of true
        IsChild = True
    Else

        Do Until intX = -1
            'find bottom level of heiarchy

            intCount = DCount("BusinessUnitID", "t_EMS_BM_BusinessUnits", "ParentUnit=" & CurrentBU)
            If intCount = 0 Then
                intX = -1
            Else
                CurrentBU = DLookup("BusinessUnitID", "t_EMS_BM_BusinessUnits", "ParentUnit=" & CurrentBU)
                intX = 0
            End If
        Loop

        'reset sentinal value
        intX = 0

        Do Until intX = -1
            'tree up until the record matches the TargetBU or reaches the top "0"
            If CurrentBU = TargetBU Or CurrentBU = 0 Then
                IsChild = True
                intX = -1
            Else
                'move up to the next level
                CurrentBU = Nz(DLookup("ParentUnit", "t_EMS_BM_BusinessUnits", "BusinessUnitID = " & CurrentBU), 0)
                IsChild = False
                intX = 0
            End If
        Loop

    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Does your data still reside in sql server? If so, you could easily create a procedure which containst the recursive cte and receives any parameters needed for filtering and such. If the data actually resides in Access well...recursive ctes are not going to work.

Comment: like @SeanLange says, you can either create a view in SQL Server and link to that in Access, use a pass-through query in Access (which will save the query in Access but execute the T-SQL in SQL server) or use a stored procedure and call that via ADO to get your data into a recordset.

Comment: Steve, it sounds like you will have no access til SQL Server. Thus, you will have to use VBA. This can run quite fast, in fact if you can copy data to a local table, extremely fast.

Comment: I guess some additional details would have been helpful.  Access is my front end application with SQL Server 2014 as my back end.  All my tables are linked via a DNS-Less connection, which seems to be the root of my problem in this scenario.  Thank you @Brad for the pass-thru recommendation.  I incorporated a pass-thru query into the application and it's working well so far.